# How do I change the color of javascript text?

Tags: javascript

So I have some JavaScript that creates separate text.

When I call it, to make the typing text, I do something like:

```
<center><p id="w00t"><font color="white">text here</font></p></center>

<script type="text/javascript">

new TypingText(document.getElementById("w00t"), 50, function(i){ var ar = new Array("\\", "|", "/", "-"); return " " + ar[i.length % ar.length]; });

//Type out examples:
TypingText.runAll();
</script>
```

But, the background of my webpage is black, and it prints the line ending array:

```
new Array("\\", "|", "/", "-"); return " " + ar[i.length % ar.length]; });
```

as black.

How would I make it white?

Comment: ZOMG you used a `font` tag. Deprecation police, get him.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the font tag first and foremost. It's not used anymore and you certainly don't need it in this case.

To colour the text, use the following code:

```
document.getElementById("w00t").style.color = "#FFFFFF";
```

Comment: That would make his text black.

Comment: Haha, yes. Updated. Think it's bedtime for me!

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would be careful of what tags you use. `<center><font>` have both been deprecated and soon won't be supported.

Use classes or styles to change the text color.

```
#w00t
{
color:white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm assuming you're old school with the `<font>` tag, etc., add this to your `<head>` so it looks something like this:

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            background-color:#000; // background color black
            color:#FFF; // font color white
        }
    </style>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS styling.  Set the style.color of the element to the color you want.